# Python 3 on Mac : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I want to import a package called mglearn that I installed in Python 3.

But keep getting the following error;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'
```

I installed this package using the following command
(I have multiple Python environments on the same MAC.)

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org mglearn
```

I'm not sure if the following is the right way to confirm mglearn installed in Python3 but saw this;

```
$ python3 -c "help('modules')"|grep mglearn
_curses_panel       cmath               mglearn             stringprep
```

The PATH of my Mac is

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/firstname.surname/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/bin/:/Users/firstname.surname/.pyenv/shims:/Users/firstname.surname/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to import mglearn?

Comment: `!pip install mglearn` did you try this

Comment: Rajarshi Das. Thank you for the comment. I tried, and seems like this tires to install the package in Python 2.7, not 3.6. 
$ !pip install mglearn
pip install -U mglearn install mglearn
Requirement already up-to-date: mglearn in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install

Comment: `python3 -m pip ...` is the right way to install with 3.x. Why do you think it is not installed?  What does `python3 -c "import mglearn; print(dir(mglearn))"` do?  (In other words, are you sure you were running python3 when import failed?

Comment: I think it is installed, cause I could confirm mglearn when I did  `python3 -c "help('modules')"| grep mglearn` . I think I was using python3 cause I used IPython and saw this. `$ ipython
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38)`

Comment: I did `python3 -c "import mglearn; print(dir(mglearn))"` and got `
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`. so installed scipy `python3.6 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org scipy` but still `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'` so did `python3 -c "import mglearn; print(dir(scipy))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined`. I think I'm getting close, any more kind advices?

Comment: I did this again `python3 -c "import mglearn; print(dir(mglearn))"
['ReBl', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__'... 'tools']` . seems like this time mglearn is installed. but still getting the same import error. is my PATH okay?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `pip install mglearn`, after commenting out PATH for Python 2.7 in ~/.bash_profile so that PATH for Python 3.6 is only available. I could install mglearn and import mglearn. Maybe because I use Anaconda, pip command was necessary to install the package (This is just my guess.). Anyway, I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage the python versions. *pyenv* allows you to set the python version (3.* or 2.*) globally, locally (in a specific project) or even in the current shell session (do some tests for example). Here is a short [post](http://bizhishui.com/Manage-Pythons) on how to install and use pyenv on Ubuntu and Mac.