# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'

Tags: python

This is a commmon question, but nothing worked for me so far.
I have seen this answer too [Python 3 on Mac : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920478/python-3-on-mac-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mglearn)

```
!pip install mglearn
!pip install sklearn
!pip install -U scikit-learn

import mglearn
import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fe22f30497b9> in <module>
----> 1 import mglearn
  2 import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mglearn'
```

I checked other questions but failed to solve it. I have macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install mglearn
```

Try using this. This assures that you are using the pip version associated with the environment.

Comment: There's an easier command to do this in modern Jupyter now (was actually already there in 2021 when this was written since it was added in 2019). These two lines can be replaced by running in your notebook `%pip install mglearn` and then restarting the kernel. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about **the magic install commands** added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the jupyter notebook from anaconda or any of the distributions and there is still problems, install the jupyter notebook with pip , by running the command pip install jupyter on your cmd. Afterwards , launch the jupyter notebook from the cmd by just typing jupyter notebook . This version of jupyter notebook installed using pip work well with mglearn module rather than conda or anaconda distributions. Open any file and import your module , you are good to go.

Comment: I'd add a word of caution to "After installing the jupyter notebook from anaconda ..., install the jupyter notebook with pip ". This has been known to help in severe cases but probably should only be used as a last resort. Mixing and matching Anaconda and pip to install Jupyter is inviting a headache generally. In the case of the referenced package there is no Anaconda recipe that I can find so you can try running `%pip install mglearn` in your Anaconda-installed Jupyter and that should enable `mglearn` to be useable.